# Why using a single hash bucket hash table in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the implementation of linux kernel's hash table. What I don't understand is that I find code initializing a hash table with only a single hash bucket. I don't know why the coding is doing that.

**This hash table usage makes sense to me:**

In `kernel/pid.c`:

```c
void __init pidhash_init(void)
{
    unsigned int i, pidhash_size;

    pid_hash = alloc_large_system_hash("PID", sizeof(*pid_hash), 0, 18,
                       HASH_EARLY | HASH_SMALL,
                       &pidhash_shift, NULL,
                       0, 4096);
    pidhash_size = 1U << pidhash_shift;

    for (i = 0; i < pidhash_size; i++)
        INIT_HLIST_HEAD(&pid_hash[i]);
}
```

`pid_hash` is a list of `struct hlist_head`, so each entry in the list represents a hash bucket.

**However this usage doesn't make sense to me:**

In `drivers/android/binder.c` of goldfish branch:

```c
static HLIST_HEAD(binder_dead_nodes);
```

It expands to

```c
struct hlist_head name = {  .first = NULL }
```

Basically it is a hash table with only one `hlist_head`, namely a hash table with only one hash bucket. So it is actually a double linked list. Why people wants to create a hash table with a single hash bucket like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hlist` is just a regular double linked list.

The difference between `list` and `hlist` is just that `hlist` trades O(1) access to the tail of the list for a 50% memory reduction for empty lists. This is perfect for hash tables, which have lots of empty lists and never need to access a list in reverse or from behind.

However, it's also great for regular linked lists.

By using `hlist` they saved a few bytes over `list`, and gave us a strong signal that the list is used to collect an unknown number of items in an order that doesn't matter.

Comment: Why it conveys a signal that the order doesn't matter? Because you still need to iterate over the double linked list. Or it is just kind of a convention in linux kernel?

Comment: @darklord Usually you want items sequentially (by insertion order), sorted, or you don't care. `hlist` doesn't readily allow sequential or sorted order since you can't efficiently append or index. It's very possible that the code calls for a stack/LIFO, but it's more common in practice to just need something to insert and iterate over without any ordering requirements.